# What is the energy source for the spice-sandworm cycle?

Tags: dune, biology

The lifecycle of the Maker apparently contains stages when it produces spice (actually its precursor), and stage when it feeds on sand plankton, which are said to consume spice.

**Where is the source of energy for the whole food chain? Where are the autotrophic organisms?**

Are the sand plankton photosynthetisating, or are the sandtrouts using geothermal power?